# Getting selected element in collection with AngularJS. Declarative approach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, I need to apply some CSS rule to one element of collection that is meant to be selected.

```
<div ng-repeat="fragments" ng-click="makeSelected()"></div>

$scope.fragments = [
   {id: 6379, someProperty: "someValue" },
   {id: 8934, someProperty: "someValue" },
   {id: 1654, someProperty: "someValue" },
   {id: 5654, someProperty: "someValue" }
];
$scope.selectedFragmentId = 6379;
```

The obvious implementation of `makeSelected` function is to attach a class name `selected` to div that was clicked then launch a loop through other elements and remove class name `selected` from them.

Also I need to "select" the particular div without clicking on them, only by passing id of selected fragment in some function. Obviously, this function also must have a loop that will go through fragments and will compare `selectedFragmentId` with every fragment ids.

My approach looks ok, but I have a bad feeling that it is so imperative instead of declarative. This is not the way in the spirit of angularjs. So, here is a question: is there a way to implement my functionallity in declarative way, without using loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any loops.

```
<div ng-class="{selected: fragment.id == selectedFragmentId}" ng-repeat="fragment in fragments" ng-click="makeSelected()"></div>
```

Then, if you set `$scope.selectedFragmentId`, div for selected fragment automatically set class to `selected`